# Images in recyclerView GridLayoutManager are not displaying correctly

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I am trying to display images in recyclerview with 3 columns....But they are not displaying correcly
[This is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOdqS.jpg)

```
recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 3);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    postList = new ArrayList<>();
    myFotosAdapter = new MyFotosAdapter(getContext(), postList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(myFotosAdapter);
```

And this is the xml code of recyclerview

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clipToPadding="false"

            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this solution

```
         <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
         android:id="@+id/recycler_view"/>
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"

```
         app:spanCount="3" />
```

Comment: Check your row view xm files